# Sending keyboard input to Notepad++ via windows api in Python

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

I'm aware of the fact that not all windows process keyboard input. However, ONE of the windows of my Notepad++ tree should have an effect on the editor, i.e. write the 'A' that I'm trying to send. I have tried all child windows but nothing works:

```
def mycallback(hwnd, data):
    data[hwnd] = win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, mycallback, data)
    return True

mywindows = {}
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(197788, mycallback, mywindows) # 197788 is the notepad++ handle whose parent is 0

# at this point, mywindows contains: {'#32770': 66908, 'Button': 66922, 'Static': 66924, 'SysTabControl32': 132272, 'Scintilla': 132276, 'splitterContainer': 263444, 'wespliter': 328982, 'msctls_statusbar32': 394476, 'dockingManager': 394474, 'wedockspliter': 132328, 'nsdockspliter': 132336, 'ReBarWindow32': 66906, 'ToolbarWindow32': 66902, 'Edit': 66914}

for v in mywindows.values():
 win32api.SendMessage(v, win32con.WM_CHAR, 0x41, 0) # trying to send an 'A' to notepad++ without knowing to which window I need to send it to. I had already noticed before that sending the 'A' to the "Edit" window doesn't work (the EXACT same win32api.SendMessage command works for the "Edit" window of the Microsoft-Windows-notepad-editor by the way)
# the return values of this loop are: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

Only the "Edit" window returns 1. And 1 means error, so I'm assuming "Edit" is the right window to target but why does it return error?

And by the way: the "Edit" window of the Microsoft-Windows-notepad-editor also returns 1, but it prints the 'A' to the editor.

Comment: In Notepad++, the "Scintilla" child window is the main text editor. Scintilla is a 3rd party text editor library that offers advanced capabilites that the standard "Edit" control doesn't. And you should be using `PostMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()`. And you should be posting `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` messages and letting Notepad's message queue generate its own `WM_CHAR` messages. But why are you using window messages at all, instead of using `SendInput()` or UI Automation?

Comment: Call [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) after `SendMessage()` get `0` indicate that there is no error.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but nothing works. It doesn't matter whether I target the Scintilla hwnd or the Edit hwnd, whether I use SendMessage or PostMessage, whether I use WM_KEY(UP|DOWN) or WM_CHAR. The letter never appears in Notepad++. Not sure if you read that part, so I'll repeat it: it WORKS for Microsoft notepad! That's so weird. Calling GetLastError returns a 6, ALWAYS! Even after a reboot and after succesfully sending a char to microsoft notepad. I think that 6 ("invalid handle") is from a call in the past where I had a typo or something.

Comment: EDIT: It works now. I have no idea why or what I did wrong before. This time there are multiple Scintilla children. One of them prints the letter to the editor. But check my approach from above: I've sent messages to ALL children, I could not have missed the right target window. No idea why it didn't work before.